# AH00157: Couldn't add listener to pollset; check system or user limits

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, httpd

Firstly thank you for helping...

Apache crashes and getting log files, How can I solve this error?

**/var/log/httpd/error_log**

```
...
...
[mpm_prefork:emerg] [pid 19347] (22)Invalid argument: AH00157: Couldn't add listener to pollset; check system or user limits
...
...
```

**Apache version**

```
Apache/2.4.10 (Unix)
```

**ulimit -a**

```
[root@ns20 ~]# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 515168
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 55000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 515168
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

**/etc/security/limits.conf**

```
* soft nofile 55000
* hard nofile 60000
```

**free -g**

```
[root@ns ~]# free -g
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            62         60          2          0          1         38
-/+ buffers/cache:         20         42
Swap:            1          0          0
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem.

"With kernel 3.2.9  to 3.2.17 there was an arbitrary limitation on epoll path (1000) which cause apache to deadlock when having 1001+ process"

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54502

Solution: Update your kernel

Best Regards